# Excel 2007/2010/2016 - Get External Data From Web - "An error has occurred in the script" and generally crashes

Tags: excel, excel-external-data

For years I have been downloading data from certain web sites via Excel's Get External Data->From Web function. In Excel 2007,2010,2016 on various PCs and laptops running various Windows operating systems, the one thing that is consistent is the incredible unreliability. I have always got multiple "An error has occurred in the script on this page" errors (to which I click Yes), and as often as not it just hangs and I have to terminate Excel in Task Manager.

E.g. if I go to www.ft.com, I get 3 "An error has occurred in the script" messages at line 1. I then click on login, I get two more error messages. I am then completely unable to type in the email address field to login. I have to terminate Excel to exit. Over the years I have managed to get through this incredible unreliability one way or another, but now I have hit a dead end.

I get similar behaviour on most websites. E.g. www.morningstar.co.uk.

It appears that Excel uses a different version of IE for its queries. So I cannot login using IE11 or Edge and then use that login to go straight to the relevant data page on ft.com that I want to access. I have to login to FT.com via Excel

Very frustrating. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you scraping when you could just use the site's API?

Comment: I hadn't realised there is an API, but scraping is free whereas the API seems to be aimed at corporates and doesn't come cheap!

Comment: When that error pops up, you have the option to not show that popup again in IE (I don't remember the exact method but in the popup go to setting and set it not to show again). Is that not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be an option. And the pop shows that there is an error in the website which is presumably why I can't login (via excel)

Comment: @drb01 actually, according to the API Documentation the API's "[Headline License]"  is ompletely free as long as you can keep it under 5000 calls per day (or 2 calls/second).

Comment: yes thank you, have just been getting into it. It seems to be a whole new learning curve! But, even if the FT API works, I just gave www.ft.com as an example. The same problem occurs with lots of web pages - I just don't understand how it can have been so unreliable for so many years!! I originally assumed it was my setup, but several PCs and windows/office versions later the same problems persist.

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't so much an answer as a workaround. It is easy to write some VBA to load the data using Internet Explorer (i.e IE11 as installed separately on your PC) rather than going via the Excel-Get Data from Web function. E.g. see this link

[Transferring webpage data to an Excel Worksheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458725/transferring-webpage-data-to-an-excel-worksheet-using-vba)

It copies the entire web page without formatting, but this was good enough for my purposes.

I am still puzzled why the Excel-Get Data from Web function continues to be so extremely unreliable after so many years